# Invalid signup in Spring boot with Auth0

Tags: spring, spring-boot, authentication, auth0

I'm following this Quickstart guide: https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/webapp/java-spring-security-mvc to create an authorization flow in which my back end handles the login/signup before forwarding the session to an SPA.

I downloaded the sample application, created a new Auth0 application and filled in the auth0.properties file with the required values from my Auth0 application, and added the callback and logout URLs as instructed. The app runs, but upon filling out the signup form I get this error in the signup request:

```
{"name":"BadRequestError","code":"invalid_signup","description":"Invalid sign up","statusCode":400}
```

I checked the values being sent in the signup payload and they all conform to the values expected. This is about as "out of the box" as can be expected but it still doesn't work, and I'm unsure of how to proceed.

Comment: You can find more detailed error information on the "Logs" menu item on your Dashboard on auth0.com . This URL is not correct, but something like this: https://manage.auth0.com/ - Logs

Comment: Will take a look at that, thank you!